# Using Bundle to send data from activity to fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, dialog

I am trying to use Bundle to send data from an activity to a fragment. The activity is receiving the input from a dialogbox when the user clicks on the actionbar add icon. The button also opens the dialogbox but it sends the data straight to the fragment (I'm trying to learn the difference between activity and fragment and to interact with the dialogfragment). None of the solutions on the internet have worked for me, and I was hoping someone can help

I have provided a visualization to aid in my explanation of the issue. So initially, I click the action add icon that opens the dialogbox (2nd pic), when I enter an input, it doesn't alter the data on the fragment. Only when I press the action add icon for a second time, does the first input get updated (3rd pic). Also you may notice that it says "Bundle{[Dialog Input = First Input]}" where First Input is the user input. How do I change this to just, First Input. I tried clearing the textview before setting the value, but that doesn't work. Now lastly when I press the button, it opens the dialogbox and when I enter in data, the data from the action add icon (handled in activity then data sent to fragment) overlaps with the data from the button (data sent straight to fragment). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
MyCustomDialog.OnInputSelected{

public String dialogInput;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;

@Override
public void sendInput(String input) {
    dialogInput = input;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Inflate the menu, this adds items to the action bar if it is present
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    //Handle action bar clicks here. The action bar will automatically handle clicks on the home/up button
    //so long as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml

    switch(item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.action_add:
            MyCustomDialog dialog = new MyCustomDialog();
            dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "MyCustomDialog");

            //Trying Bundle to pass data, dialog input between activity and fragment
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("Dialog Input", dialogInput);
            //Set Fragment class arguments
            MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle); //set argument bundle to fragment

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MainFragment,fragment).commit(); //now replace Mainfragment


            Toast.makeText(this, "Action_Add Clicked Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

MainFragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements MyCustomDialog.OnInputSelected{

TextView InputDisplay;
Button OpenDialog;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    InputDisplay = view.findViewById(R.id.InputDisplay);
    OpenDialog = view.findViewById(R.id.Open_Dialog);

    //Getting Main Activity dialog information with Bundle, that was received from toolbar add
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if(bundle != null){
        String dialogInput = bundle.toString();
        //Clearing since Fragment call and activity call overlap each other.
        InputDisplay.setText("");
        InputDisplay.clearComposingText();
        InputDisplay.setText(dialogInput);
    }
    //String dialogInput = this.getArguments().getString("Dialog Input");

    OpenDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("MainFragment", "onClick: opening dialog");

            MyCustomDialog customDialog = new MyCustomDialog();
            customDialog.setTargetFragment(MainFragment.this, 1);
            customDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "MyCustomDialog");
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void sendInput(String input) {
    InputDisplay.setText("");
    InputDisplay.setText(input);
}
}
```

My Custom Dialog:

```
public class MyCustomDialog extends DialogFragment {

private EditText Input;
private TextView ActionOK, ActionCANCEL;

private OnInputSelected onInputSelected;

public interface OnInputSelected{
    void sendInput(String input);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try{
        Fragment onInputSelected_fragment = getTargetFragment();
        Activity onInputSelected_activity = getActivity();
        if(onInputSelected_fragment != null){
            onInputSelected = (OnInputSelected) onInputSelected_fragment;
        }else{
            onInputSelected = (OnInputSelected) onInputSelected_activity;
        }
        //throw new RuntimeException("Custom Dialog onAttach Listener was NULL");
    }catch(ClassCastException e){
        Log.e("Custom Dialog", "onAttach: ClassCastException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_my_custom, container, false);

    Input = view.findViewById(R.id.Input);
    ActionOK = view.findViewById(R.id.Action_OK);
    ActionCANCEL = view.findViewById(R.id.Action_CANCEL);

    ActionCANCEL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });

    ActionOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onInputSelected.sendInput(Input.getText().toString());

            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I change this to just, First Input.

your output is printed like this "Bundle{[Dialog Input = First Input]}" because you are **directly doing bundle.toString();** instead of getting the value you have stored in the bundle.
change the above to this

```
String dialogInput = bundle.getString("Dialog Input")
InputDisplay.setText(dialogInput);
```

> the data from the action add icon overlaps with the data from the button

Clear the existing text in the text view before setting the new value like this

```
String dialogInput = bundle.getString("Dialog Input")
InputDisplay.setText(");
InputDisplay.setText(dialogInput);
```

Also, I noticed that all the variable names that you have used are **not following camel case** I suggest you correct that as well.

Comment: I've tried bundle.getString("Dialog Input"); before, but whenever I use that I get NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Comment: I have cleared my code using setText but strangely they still overlap

Comment: What do you mean by "not following camel case"?

Comment: Npe That means the data is not getting set to bundle, camel case read about it it's a programming best practice